# Clearcase : Migrate from Git to ClearCase

Tags: git, clearcase

Could you please share your experience with Git to Clearcase migration ?

As we need to convert our repo to CC and keep history.

Comment: Wow, you are doing the exact opposite of the rest of the world :)

Comment: The answer to this is to try to forget about keeping the history as quickly as possible and focusing on other requirements instead. Unless it is a very small repository. To give any recommendations i think you have to provide more information about the repository. Especially the branch situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real "experience" of such a migration, but if you need to keep the history, you can do so easily for one branch (like master), it is more difficult for multiple branches:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset . m:\MyView\MyVob\ParentDirectory' HEAD
```

For each commit of the git repo, you do a clearfsimport, in order to add or update files in a ClearCase dynamic view (as explained in "[Creating a new subdirectory structure in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418196/6309)")

See more about the [`filter-branch --tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) filter in "[Rewrite git history replacing a word in every single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19906845/6309)", used usually to [rewrite history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), but used here to for another purpose (`clearfsimport`).